# linux "find" command

Tags: linux, bash, find, sh

I have a problem with a bash script. 
I have something like this:

```
find /home -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -not -empty -type d | sort
```

and the output is like :

```
/home/dir1
/home/dir2
```

I want the output to be :

```
dir1
dir2
```

Answer (score 4):

You can configure the output with `-printf`

```
find /home -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -not -empty -type d -printf "%f\n" | sort
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [basename](http://linux.die.net/man/1/basename)(1):

```
find /home -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -not -empty -type d -exec basename {} \; |sort
```

Answer (score 0):

Just attach `-exec basename {} \;` to your find command.

```
find /home -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -not -empty -type d -exec basename {} \; | sort
```

Answer (score 0):

`find /home -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -not -empty -type d -exec basename {} \; | sort`